# reduce a combination eliminating rows with more than two consecutives

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

im trying to have this working and printing to a file because is faster, but I dont know why it prints 7 lines from each result ending with a enormous file, what I am doing wrong? 
I want 7 numbers selected from 1 to 56 with no more than 2 consecutives in each iteration, a permutation gives something like 230 million results so I think this must be smaller,
Thank you!

```
from itertools import combinations, groupby
from operator import itemgetter
f= open('7.txt','w')

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
        12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
        20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,
        28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,
        36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,
        44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,
        52,53,54,55,56]

def find_consecutive(lst, min_string=3):
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda (i,x):i-x):
        num_string = map(itemgetter(1), g)
        if len(num_string) >= 3:
            yield num_string

for i in combinations(data, 7):
    if not any(find_consecutive(i, min_string=3)):
            for x in i:
                f.write(str(i))
                f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code can be simplified like below.

**Changes:**

- please note that I have replaced file write code with print for ease of testing
- I have changed your data to range
- Changed has_consecutive_number function
- write x to file instead of i

```py
from itertools import combinations, groupby, count
from operator import itemgetter

data = range(1,57)

def has_consecutive_number(lst, min_string=3):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    consecutives = [i-j for i,j in zip(lst[1:], lst[:-1])].count(1)
    if consecutives<min_string:
        return True

    return False

with open('7.txt','w') as f:
    for i in combinations(data, 7):
        if has_consecutive_number(i, min_string=3):
            print(i)
            for x in i:
                print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, Im having this error, what do I need to do to /// if not any(find_consecutive(i, min_string=3)):
NameError: name 'find_consecutive' is not defined

Comment: sorry, there was some bug I corrected the  code now

Comment: It worked jut an issue because like it is it prints both solutions in the shell i and x, and to avoid having 1,2,3 at the beginning had to change the min_string to =2, but so far is working, thank you!

Comment: welcome, plz consider mark it resolved and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

`find_consecutive` does not do what you think it does.

Try this simpler function:

```
def has_consecutive(lst, min_repeat=3):
    if not lst:
        return False
    last = lst[0]
    counter = 1
    for n in lst[1:]:
        if n == last:
            counter += 1
            if min_repeat <= counter:
                return True
        else:
            counter = 1
            last = n
    return False

for c in combinations(data, 7):
    if not has_consecutive(c):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you! It still gives consecutive values, what am I doing wrong

Comment: Another issue is that you wrote `for x in i: write(i)` which should just be `write(i)`